# AMD Radeon RX 6600M driver issue in Ubuntu 22.04 when use a second display / monitor

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, radeon, wayland, amdgpu

i would like to have your help. I have a HP Omen 16 laptop (16-c0012dx) with AMD Ryzen 7 and AMD Radeon RX 6600M dedicated graphic card, there i have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

[image]

The AMD Ryzen has an integrated graphic card that i believe is using normally all the time if i am not playing games for example; in my understand the HDMI port is joined to the dedicated graphic card and there is where i have the problem.

If i use a second display / monitor to extend the desktop, it works, but if i lock the screen manually or the system lock it automatically by inactivity, the system closes the session, when i unlock the screen is like i am starting session again, all the applications i had open where closed, that is when i am using Wyland by default.

If i use Xorg instead of Wyland, it's worst because the second display works for a while, but after it frozen and keep black like is disconnected, until i restart the system, so is unusable.

I believe this is not problem of Wayland, Xorg, or even Gnome, but a bug of the AMD Radeon driver; since the AMDGPU driver is open source is included in the Linux kernel already, i don't have to install it like in the case of NVidia.

I tried to install the AMD Radeaon driver manually, downloading the deb package for Ubuntu 22.04 from here:
https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers

sudo apt install ./amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb

After that i installed the All-Open use case with the following command:
amdgpu-install -y --usecase=graphics

I used the official documentation:
https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html

I restarted the system and i tried again, but the issue persist. Do you have any idea how to solve it? or i have to wait until an Ubuntu kernel update bring the bug fix.

**UPDATE**

Here i share more information about the two graphics cards (integrated and dedicated), although i think the problem here is with the dedicated graphic card:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have almost the same issue. AMD® Radeon rx 6600m graphics card. Plugging in a second monitor or waking up the laptop after inactivity kills the current session. The same thing happens when I try to change the monitor layout in the settings, which means I'm stuck with the default layout.

Comment: Yes, the same issue as me. No matter if use Xorg or Wayland, looks like the problem is the driver.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on my omen laptop with Radeon 6600M graphics card on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

```
root@starcastle:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Drivers (amdgpu-install_22.20.50205-1_all.deb) were installed by command

```
# amdgpu-install -y --usecase=graphics
```

Earlier when i were on ubuntu 20.04 LTS, i had written to AMD to TECH.SUPPORT@amd.com, and they had responsed me that

> driver link which you have provided us (https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-40-2) will only support on Rx 6600
> desktop graphics card and since you have Rx 6600M mobile GPU hence
> this graphics card driver will not support in your laptop.
>
> If your laptop does support Ubuntu 22.04 then you may use Linux OS
> inbuilt driver.

I think that newer driver 22-20 https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-22-20 supprorts only Rx 6600 desktop graphics card (not Rx 6600m). You should consider installation of the **xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu** package, which may consist proper driver but i have the same problem with this package.

Comment: The open-source `amdgpu` is already included, selected during the OS installation if compatible hardware is found, and should be running without any user intervention.

Comment: I don't believe is a support problem, the AMD Radeon RX6600M is supported very well with the official driver, i can play AAA games like "Control" or "Hellblade" without issues, it's just a bug in that specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer so much as a potential root cause.  I have the same model Omen laptop, and I've been struggling with intermittent boot issues.  Using the "nomodeset" flag in GRUB allows me to boot consistently, but that disables advanced graphics features so it's not a proper solution.  After a couple weeks of science and online research, I finally came across an idea and checked "lspci" to see the codenames of both the integrated Ryzen 5800H graphics controller and the 6600M.  They are called "Cezanne" and "Navi 23," respectively.  I checked the [contents of the "amdgpu" kernel module](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu) and found that there are no binaries for either device included.

[Ryzen7-5800H_integrated_GPU_codename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU1FR.jpg)

[Radeon-6600M_GPU_codename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNdQh.jpg)

So, it appears that the kernel is missing the drivers for our specific graphics controllers. :(

I have not yet found a source/procedure to get them installed.  When/if I do, I'll post back here.

**UPDATE**

So, according to linux-hardware.org, the [Cezanne](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1002-1638-103c-8902) and [Navi 23](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1002-73ff-103c-8902) are OK.  I did a probe using "hw-probe" and both GPUs report as working.  However, I did see in the **vulkaninfo** log that in my Kubuntu 22.10 installation the 5800H integrated GPU isn't identified properly, just saying *unknown*.  I booted to a 20.04.5 live USB installer and did the same operation.  There is no **vulkaninfo** log to be had there.  Doing more science, 20.04.5 boots fine every time.

I moved up to a 22.04.1 live USB installer and did the "hw-probe" again.  It took several tries to get it to boot properly, just like my 22.10 install.  This time, the **vulkaninfo** log there claimed to identify both GPUs, but both were identified incorrectly.

I took a look at the kernel builds in both USB installers, and they're both 5.15, but the one included in 20.04.5 is actually a slightly **newer** build than the 22.04.1 installer.  But since 20.04.5 boots correctly 100% of the time so far, I don't think it's a kernel module info anymore.  The HW IDs are showing up fine in everything I've tried (20.04.5+), and since linux-hardware.org has several reports of things working driver-wise I think I can rule that out.  The absence of a **vulkaninfo** in 20.04.5 and that at least one GPU is misidentified by Vulkan everywhere it's misbehaving, I'm thinking there's something related here.  More research and updates to come...

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar (or maybe identical) laptop, HP Omen 16, and similar problems (screen corruption on HDMI-attached monitor). I use Mate/X11.

When I run graphics programs on main laptop display everything runs fine, but when I do it on monitor connected to the HDMI port screen can become corrupt and frozen, with checkboard-like artifacts. The interesting thing is: windows dragged from the corrupted HDMI screen to the main laptop screen were still normally behaving and running.

So for me the problem looks like this: main laptop display is connected to the integrated graphics card (Cezanne), and HDMI to dedicated one (Navi 23). So when HDMI display is being utilized data has to pass from iGPU through dGPU, and the latter sometimes hangs during the process.

Looking for a solution I came across this discussion:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1974
and this one:
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Gaming-Notebooks/HP-OMEN-16-Black-artifacts/td-p/8343419/page/7

Conclusions from both threads are that power management of the Navi card is somehow handled incorrectly. In the second thread one can find a link to github repository:
https://github.com/kb2288/amd-gpu

I compiled the program and it looks it helped, but currently I'm using simpler solution. I run:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgear
```

Even when the window is minimized it keeps dGPU awake.

No hangups since then.